# Is it bad to bring an Android phone to an Apple On-site Interview?

Tags: interviewing

I know Apple employees are passionate Apple fans. I do have an old iPhone that I can use. Should I just bring my old iPhone with me to the interview?

Comment: Do you think they check your phone before they start the interview?

Comment: @SmallChess This should be a referenced answer, rather than a comment. In my experience, most companies don't think worse of you for using their competitors products - if Apple have a specific policy/culture that's different, that fact needs backed up.

Comment: @SmallChess What are you talking about? Apple doesn't and cannot control what devices employees use. If you mean *when they're on the job*, then sure, an iPhone might be required for some employees, since Apple is the developer of iOS. But Apple employees are of course free to purchase and use whatever phones they want. Apple doesn't care.

Comment: This is tricky... Some 20+ years ago, as I remember it, the CEO of Jaguar was driving BMW, Mercedes, R-R and other cars on a daily basis. When asked why, he said: "I need to know why people like them, and if they have better features than ours, so Jaguar can improve, and we'll still have better cars" (roughly translated, but the idea is here). SO, no, you don't need to wear an Apple watch to make a positive impression, I guess a Rolex is fine :)

Comment: They should not see your phone.  Don't take phone calls during an interview.

Comment: @paparazzo I'm definitely not taking phone calls during any interview. But I'd look like a psychopath if I go through the entire day without taking my phone out of my pocket once.

Comment: @josh a psychopath? really? I'd just assume you were being attentive to your interview process, assuming I even noticed at all!

Comment: @OldPadawan Most of the auto makers own a fleet of their competitors' cars and require that some of its management and engineering staffs spend some time in them.

Comment: Bring a Windows phone, instant hire :)

Comment: Phone developers should, must, own and use a wide variety of devices.  If you happen to have a particular Samsung or whatever on you on one particular day, any professional will see it as just that.  You're not a "civilian" user of phones where you "use" one of the OSs.

Comment: @Josh I guess I'm a psychopath every day, since I don't carry a phone...

Answer (score 27):

It doesn't matter.

Ideally, you won't be taking your phone out of your pocket during an interview anyway.

So don't worry about it and concentrate on your interview.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I just bring my old iPhone with me to the interview?

Keep your phone in your pocket or your bag or leave it in your car. That way nobody will notice or care what operating system it uses.

Answer (score 3):

In general, I agree with Snow. You're applying for a position at Apple though, questions about your favourite brand may show up. Answer them truthfully. You don't want to say, "I'm currently using an iPhone", refering to your old phone, when in reality you're using an Android on a daily basis. They'll notice on your first day anyway. Try to spin it around in a good way. As an example, I heard someone mention this in a conversation just yesterday.

> I wish I had gone for another iPhone instead of this Android. It seemed good on paper, but I really miss features X and Y from iPhones.

If it is relevant for you, you could use this phrase, or another one that is positive and true.

Comment: Unless this is actually true (and the OP hasn't indicated one way or another) I'd be wary of saying that.

Comment: @motosubatsu Which is why it is an example and I said "answer truthfully". If it is not the truth, obviously don't use it.

Comment: My apologies.. I'd managed to miss that bit completely - obviously my brain isn't firing on all cylinders today! I've reversed my DV

Comment: @motosubatsu No worries. It may have been a bit ambiguous too. I just made an edit that aims to clarify it.